# Implement Vertical Sliding drawer for API > 17

Tags: android, android-layout, slidingdrawer

[image]

I want similar drawer pattern, in which view can be expanded vertically through Handle.

Any help on this will be appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can  use [`SlidingDrawer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) in API 17+. It being deprecated means it's no longer maintained, but you can still implement one.